# Look-up of remote ejb using client-ejb jar

Tags: java, ejb, weblogic, lookup

I have application packed as an .ear file with ejb module inside. There is stateless session bean implementing remote interface. Something like this:

```
package my.package.ext.impl;  
[...]
@Stateless(name = "MyPropertiesHandler", mappedName = "ejb/MyPropertiesHandler")
public class PropertiesHandler implements PropertiesHandlerRemote {
    [...]
}
```

and this:

```
package my.package.ext;  
[...]    
@Remote
public interface PropertiesHandlerRemote {
    [...]
}
```

There's also client-ejb jar generated, there are business remote interface and some other stuff inside.
This client-ejb jar is attached to other application as a Maven dependency.
I try to look-up PropertiesHandler service from this application:

```
PropertiesHandlerRemote propertiesHandler = InitialContext.doLookup(
    "ejb/MyPropertiesHandler#my.package.ext.PropertiesHandlerRemote");
```

At this moment I get following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: my/package/ext/PropertiesHandlerRemote
at [...]
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor633.invoke(Unknown Source)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: my.package.ext.PropertiesHandlerRemote
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:297)
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:270)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:179)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

I run it on Weblogic 10.x as you can see above.
Any ideas that's going wrong?

Comment: So I believe it compiles, what scope do you set in maven for this dependency? The class is not found at runtime by WL.

Comment: @Kris thanks for reply. No scope specified, so I guess it is compile by default. Anyway it is packed as an .ear and client-ejb jar included into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the client-ejb jar was packed in the root of an ear file, not in the /lib folder with other dependencies.
The solution is to use `<classifier>client</classifier>` tag instead of `<type>ejb-client</type>` in the pom of the project where you want to use your client-ejb jar file.
This problem is also discussed here: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MEAR-85
Strange that this is the first time I met such problem, previously `<type>ejb-client</type>` tag worked perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a `NoClassDefFoundError`, it does not mean your `PropertiesHandlerRemote` class is not found, but something which is used by your implementation - so maybe you have further dependencies which are not in the client's classpath?

Comment: thanks for reply. I have original ear file deployed on the same container, so all required stuff should be on classpath. Anyway I've just tried to remove all "exclude" annotation from ejb-client generation config, so everything was included into this jar. It did not help :(

Comment: If you use your ejb from within the container, why do you have to get the reference by JNDI and don't let it injected by `@EJB`? Or are you talking about a second container trying to remotely access the ejb in the first one?

Comment: second is correct ;) I was just inaccurate. Also this bean is look-up from the simple java class, which is not in the managed context (not an ejb), so `@ejb` injection will not work.

Comment: Would it be an option to put your client within an application client container? Then it would still be a "simple java class", but you could use injection to get the reference.

Comment: But again to the root problem - `NoClassDefFoundError`simply means, a class is not found by the class loader while processing the definition of your class. So I would double-check, if your client really "sees" all the necessary classes.

Comment: do you want to say `@EJB` injection will work from outside managed context? I doubt on it :) But this is not the case anyway. Regarding to the topic, do you mean some other class could be missing? Why so stacktrace refers my/package/ext/PropertiesHandlerRemote class?